# Condition for Binary number or not

Tags: python, project

Am trying to make a simple program to convert binary number to decimal number. I'd like to first write a condtion whether to check the given number is a binary or not. 
How do i do that?
Except that, the program works normally without any errors but am afraid when a non binary number is given, it still does the job.
**Input**

```
print("Binary to Decimal")

bin = input("Give a binary number : ")
bin = [int(i) for i in bin]

powers = [i for i in range(len(bin)-1,-1,-1)]

for i in range(len(bin)):
  bin[i] = bin[i] * 2**(powers[i])
decimal = sum(bin)
print("The corresponding Decimal digit is : %d"%(decimal))
```

**Output**

```
Binary to Decimal
Give a binary number : 101
The correspnding Decimal digit is : 5
```

Also if u find any corrections or want to make any suggestions, please feel free to suggest me below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try pythonic way is *not to test*, but to try the conversion and catch the exception if the input is bad. This is the [Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission prinicple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360858/what-is-the-eafp-principle-in-python):

```
b = input("Give a binary number : ")
try:
    print(int(b, 2))
except ValueError:
    print("not binary")
```

If you still want to check an easy test is to use `all()`:

```
if all(n in ('1','0') for n in b):
   # it's all 1's and 0's
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check that if the string contains any other number rather than 0's and 1's then it is not a binary number.

Answer (score 0):

you can check with regular expression

```
import re

if re.match("^[01]+$", '011001'):
   //then proceed
else:
   //do something for non-binary
```